# Result difference between CSS selectors and querySelector function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand the console outputs of this code, especially since the CSS code targets the right element but not the querySelector function.

```js
let firstChild = document.querySelector('BODY > :first-child');
console.log(firstChild.querySelector(':first-child > :first-child'));
console.log(firstChild.querySelector(':first-child'));
```

```css
BODY > :first-child > :first-child > :first-child  {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="D1">
      <div class="D2">
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo.querySelector` matches the first element inside `foo` that the selector matches.

This:

> ```
> let firstChild = document.querySelector('BODY > :first-child');
> ```

Matches `<div class="D1">`

Then:

> ```
> firstChild.querySelector(':first-child > :first-child')
> ```

Matches `<div class="D2">` because:

- `<div class="D2">` is inside `firstChild`
- `<div class="D1">` matches `:first-child` (it is the first child of `body`)
- `<div class="D2">` matches `:first-child` (it is the first child of `D1`)

> ```
> firstChild.querySelector(':first-child')
> ```

… gives a similar result, It just doesn't care about the second condition above.

---

In short, you get different results because `querySelector` **does not** add an implicit "descendant of `foo`" to the selector itself, nor does it require that every element matched is a descendant of `foo` (only the final element needs to match that)).